# Confused about c++ constructor deletion

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, copy-initialization

This is my class

```
class A {
public:
    A(int);
    A(A const&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A& a) = delete;
// etc.
};
```

In another file I can call the constructor like this:

```
auto foo = A(123);
```

That resolves to the copy constructor and not the one I expect, why?

```
error C2280: 'mynamspace::A::A(const mynamespace::A &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. `auto foo = A(123)` obviously called the copy constructor.

Comment: @Yves Well, in modern C++, it *doesn't* call the copy constructor. It hasn't since C++17.

Comment: Maybe it depends on the version of C++ ...  GCC 4.7.1 is the first one that produces that error.  And then when Using -std=c++17 arrives with GCC 7.1 it works.

Comment: Re: your edit: it's trying to use *both* constructors. It wants to use the not-deleted one (during `A(123)`) followed by the deleted one (during `auto foo = ...`). Your code says to first construct a temporary object, then to copy it into `foo` (at least, that's what it says before C++17). The assignment operator is irrelevant (also, I think you dropped the `=` in `operator=`). In C++14 and before, you need to explicitly say you want to directly construct `foo` from `123`: `A foo(123)`. In C++17, the meaning of your code changes and it does directly construct `foo` from`123`.

Answer (score 6):

`auto foo = A(123);` performs [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), in concept, `A(123)` constructs a temporary `A` by `A::A(int)` firstly, then `foo` is copy-initialized from the temporary by the copy constructor (PS `A` doesn't have move constructor). Before C++17 the code is ill-formed because the copy constructor is marked as `delete`.

Since C++17 the copy construction is elided completely because of [mandatory copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) and the code is well-formed.

> (Since C++17) First, if `T` is a class type and the initializer is a prvalue expression whose cv-unqualified type is the same class as `T`, the initializer expression itself, rather than a temporary materialized from it, is used to initialize the destination object: see [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

and

(emphais mine)

> (Since C++17) Under the following circumstances, the compilers are required to omit the copy and move construction of class objects, even if the copy/move constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. The objects are constructed directly into the storage where they would otherwise be copied/moved to. **The copy/move constructors need not be present or accessible**:

Note that before C++17, copy elision is an optimization, even it might be performed the copy/move constructor still must be present and accessible.

> This is an optimization: even when it takes place and the copy`/move (since C++11)` constructor is not called, it still must be present and accessible (as if no optimization happened at all), otherwise the program is ill-formed:

You can upgrade your compiler to support C++17, or use [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) (to remove the requirement of usage of copy constructor).

```
A foo(123);
A foo{123};
```